# jQuery bind even to class, this is all members?

Tags: jquery

If you bind a click event to a class:

```
$(".testClass").click(  function() {
    $( this ).css( 'top' : '10px' );    
});
```

In this example, do all elements with that class get assigned the attribute value?  Is there a way to apply the attribute only to the class member that was clicked on?

This is what appears to be happening with this makeDraggable plugin I grabbed off the web (and i have modified slightly) - note that e is set = to this.  When I apply that to a class selector, all members of the class move, even though I only drag one.  Why is that?:

```
jQuery.fn.makeDraggable = function(delay) {
    if (typeof(delay) == 'undefined') delay = 200;
    var a = false, // drag active
    d = jQuery(document), // document jQuery
    e = jQuery(this), // current element
    c = e.css('cursor'), // current cursor
    p = [null,null], // clicked point
    m = null, // current mouseDown event
    t = null, // timeout id
    bl = function(e) { // blocks an event (to prevent selecting text)
            var tN = e.target.tagName;
            if( ! ( tN == "INPUT" || tN == "LABEL" || tN == "TEXTAREA" )){
               try { // will fail with IE & timeout
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  e.preventDefault();
                    } catch (e) {}; // but will still remain usable
            }
    },
    md = function(e_md) { // mousedown
            bl(e_md); // text selection would occur if not blocked here
            if (a) { // drag active
                    e.css('opacity', '0.8')
                    .css('cursor', 'move')
                    .css('outline', '2px solid #fc0')
                    .css('z-index', '20');
                    d.bind('mousemove', mm);
                    p = [e_md.clientX - e.position().left, e_md.clientY - e.position().top];
                    e.trigger('dragstart');
            } else { // just wait
                    var tN = e.target.tagName;
                    if( ! ( tN == "INPUT" || tN == "LABEL" || tN == "TEXTAREA" )){
                            m = e_md;
                            t = setTimeout(to, delay);
                    }
            }
    },
    mu = function(e_mu) { // mouseup
            if (a) { // drag active
                    bl(e_mu); // text selection would occur if not blocked here
                    d.unbind('mousemove', mm);
                    e.css('opacity', '1')
                    .css('cursor', c)
                    .css('outline', 'none')
                    .trigger('dragend');
            } 
            a = false;
            clearTimeout(t);
    },
    mm = function(e_mm) { // mousemove
            bl(e_mm); // text selection would occur if not blocked here
            e.css('left', (e_mm.clientX - p[0]) + 'px')
            .css('top', (e_mm.clientY - p[1]) + 'px');
    },
    to = function() { // timeout
            a = true;
            if (m) md(m);
    };
    e.bind('mousedown', md).bind('mouseup', mu);
    return e;
};
```

here's the initialization code:

```
 jQuery('.testClass').makeDraggable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$(".testClass").click(  function() {
    $( this ).css( 'top' : '10px' );    
});
```

Says that when a member of the `testClass` class is clicked, then its `top` CSS property should be set to `10px`.

That plugin should behave the same way. Could you post the code you use to initialize the plugin and possibly the other code in your page?

---

Fixed it.

The problem was here:

```
md = function(e_md) { // mousedown
bl(e_md); // text selection would occur if not blocked here

if (a) { // drag active
    e.css('opacity', '0.8').css('cursor', 'move').css('outline', '2px solid #fc0').css('z-index', '20');
    d.bind('mousemove', mm);
```

In this context, `e` is defined to be the selector that is used to initialize, which happens to be *all* of the elements in that class. I just redefined `e` to be `$(e_md.target)`, the target of the event.

A demo and the new code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/H2ahz/7/

Comment: I edited my post, the initialization is at the bottom of my post now. The plugin works, except that every class member moves.  Fundamentally, it does not look to be different from the simple example I used at the top of my post.

Comment: No, not really. I looked over the code, and it seems to me that only one element `e` should be animating. Can you confirm that `e` is just one element?

Comment: you're right. e = an array of all the elements.  How could that happen?

Comment: He's using `e` as both a cache for `jQuery(this)` and in `bl = function(e)`. Perhaps this is part of the problem? (I don't think so, but it is a bit confusing.)

Comment: @mblase75: can you give me the line number for this?

Comment: The function starting at line 10.

Comment: well, I didn't write the plugin, and didn't change bl = function(e) but with that function, e should be local, right?

Comment: I doubt that it would interfere, but @Gordon, could you rename that `e` to something else then? Your variable names are a bit confusing ;)

Comment: @Gordon: Check my answer again. I've fixed the problem.